# Convert Product Attribute Text to Number

Tags: magento2, product-attribute, php-7

I am trying to do a custom inventory check with some attributes that I populate, my thoughts would be that it could work something like this;

```
<?php

$_invwest = $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('inv_west');
$invwestint = (int)$_invwest;

if ($invwestint > 0) {

    echo '<div style="font-weight:bold;">In Stock</div>';

}

?>
```

However when I try to load the product page, I get this exception:

```
Exception #0 (Exception): Notice: Object of class Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Eav\Attribute\Interceptor could not be converted to int in /app/design/frontend/TEMPLATE/FOLDER/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/view/type/default.phtml on line 30
```

Any idea what else I could do here?

For examples sake, the current value in the text is '10'

---

EDIT: For more clarity;

The attribute 'inv_west' settings;

```
Catalog Input Type for Store Owner: Text Field
Attribute Code: inv_west
Scope: Global 
Allow HTML Tags on Storefront: Yes
Visible on Catalog Pages on Storefront: Yes
```

Answer (score 0):

Doing more and more extensive searching, I wasn't missing much, but to get it working like intended, my code became the following:

```
$product = $block->getProduct();
$invwest = $product->getCustomAttribute('inv_west')->getValue();

if (null !== $invwest) {

    if ($invwest > 0) { 

       echo '<div style="font-weight:bold;">In Stock</div>';

   }

}
```